# How to receive data in a perl page sent through url from another page?

Tags: perl, cgi

I am passing data via url using jquery to a perl page, how can i get that data into a variable to use it.

location.href = "../test/test1.pl?org_id="+org_val;

Comment: `$ENV{'QUERY_STRING'}` perhaps?

Comment: can you please send me the command , i am very new to perl.

Comment: That is a variable which the query string might already be in. You should check it out, e.g. `print $ENV{QUERY_STRING}`.

Comment: I tried that one out but it reflects nothing. I need to catch that "org_id" in this page and use it. So the command should be "print $ENV{org_id};" . Is it right??

Comment: Perhaps you should try the [`CGI`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI) module and refer to its documentation. There you can do `print $cgi->param('org_id')`.

Comment: Alright... I ll check n try that... Thanks a lot for your help...

Comment: Got it finally:use CGI;
$q = new CGI;
my $org_id = $q->param('org_id');

Comment: When you say "perl page" do you mean the output of a CGI script ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CGI; $q = new CGI; my $org_id = $q->param('org_id');
```